# Slack bot | check message reactions

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I'm currently developing a slack bot.
This one will ask users to add a reaction to the message once the requested task is done.
However, I have no idea how to do this task, and my api research is not successful.
I find indeed the reactions.get and the reactions.list but it doesn't seem to be the right solution.

Here is my code:

```
import os 
from slack import WebClient
from slack.errors import SlackApiError
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, MO


client = WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_KEY'])

attachments = [{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Hello ! Il est temps de remplir le formulaire d'absences.\n\n*Merci de suivre les instructions ci-dessous.*"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": ":round_pushpin: *<www.youtube.com|Clique ici pour te rendre sur la fiche d'absences.>* \nSurtout n'oublie pas de réagir avec :heavy_check_mark: afin d'indiquer que c'est bien fait."
            }
        }
    ]
}]


today = date.today()

def last_monday_of_month(any_day):
    next_month = any_day.replace(day=28) + datetime.timedelta(days=4)  # this will never fail
    last_day = next_month - datetime.timedelta(days=next_month.day)
    return last_day + relativedelta(weekday=MO(-2))

last_monday_of_month(date.today())

if today == last_monday_of_month(date.today()):
    client.chat_postMessage(channel='starterbot', text="", attachments=attachments)
    print("Success.")
else:
    print("Error.")
```

If someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [reactions.get](https://api.slack.com/methods/reactions.get) method. You simply supply the `timestamp` of the message you want to get the reactions for.

Your code looks like you are just posting a message. If you want to do something when a user reacts to the message, you need to subscribe to the [message](https://api.slack.com/events/message) events. That will mean having a running service (either use the Events API to have it post to you, or the RTM API to subscribe)