# Get message event_id from reaction_added in slack api

Tags: slack, slack-api

Using the slack_sdk in python, I am attempting to store who reacts to a message sent by the bot, and what what specific message they reacted to. The payload I get from a reaction_added lets me know who sent the message someone reacted to, but not the specific message event_id. Is there some way where I can tell what message someone reacted to?

the Payload received does not seem to carry the data I need. I checked the api docs, but couldn't find how to get more information on the event_id of a message someone reacted to.

Answer (score 0):

The Event IDs for each event are only so useful for correlating activities between events. You won't really find a way to link the actual event describing "what happened" with another event.

However, you can correlate what the events reference together. In `reaction_added` you receive a bundle of data in `item` describing what the `item_user` reacted to. When it's a message, `type` will be set to `message`, `channel` will indicate the ID of the channel where the message belongs and the `ts` value will point to a specific message ID in that channel.

If you previously received (& persisted) the message that has been reacted to, you'll need to correlate that with the `ts` and `channel` values you'll also find in each message.

If you don't have that message and need more data about it and have the appropriate permission scopes, you can use the Web API method `conversations.history` to fetch a single message [as documented here](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history#retrieving-a-single-message).

Comment: I think my goal is exactly as you mentioned in the first sentence, to correlate activities between two events. Once I send a message I store the ID of that message, and when someone reacts I would like to store the reaction they provided, as well as their user_id. The documentation you sent is useful, but I think I ended up finding a different solution (albeit, not an ideal solution) found at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718325/slack-bot-check-message-reactions. I was hoping for some way to do it on the fly, so I don't have to periodically check certain messages.

Comment: "the ts value will point to a specific message ID in that channel". 
I dont think this is true. `event_is` is **when** the event was dispatched. It has absolutely nothing to do with any message IDs which is killing me right now.